# flask_sqlalchemy object does not have attribute add when using flask_security

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I am trying to add some roles/users with flask_security but run into this issue when I try to create users with the `SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore`. So I first start by creating `user_datastore` like the [guide](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id2)

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
user_datastore = SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)
user_datastore.create_user(email='test', password='passowrd')
```

this is where I deviate from the guide and try to just create a test user. Looks like the `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` is causing me issues.

```
    self.db.session.add(model)
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Answer (score 6):

user_datastore = SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore(db, User, Role)

The above line may be the culprit here.

My resolution is below:
user_datastore = SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore(***db.session***, User, Role)

Comment: this one solved for me, but why it requires db.session?

Answer (score 3):

From this line remove Session

```py
user_datastore = SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
```

change to

```py
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
```

also imported

```py
from flask_security import SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
```

Answer (score 2):

So if you were following the example here https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id2 you will notice they use `SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore`. Before getting to this point if you have been starting off with just `flask_sqlalchemy` you would of probably already had a db session. So when I narrowed it down to the object SQLAlchemy not having `add` attribute I tried to use the `sessionmaker`. In which I was responded with db session already exists and now I have 2 sessions.

Long story short reading some docs you should use `SQLAlchemyUserDatastore` instead!