# Flask-Security 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'add' when registering new user

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I'm trying to implement the factorial pattern as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/) and [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id1). Currently, on my app.py I have this code:

```
def create_app(mode):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(mode)
    app.register_blueprint(app_blueprint)

    from models import db
    db.init_app(app)

    user_data_store = SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security = Security(app, user_data_store)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    return app
```

When I create a new user from the view registger_user.html I receive the following error:

`AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'add'`

```
File "W:\myApp\envs\myApp_app\lib\site-packages\flask_security\views.py", line 118, in register
user = register_user(**form.to_dict())
File "W:\myApp\envs\myApp_app\lib\site-packages\flask_security\registerable.py", line 29, in register_user
user = _datastore.create_user(**kwargs)
File "W:\myApp\envs\myApp_app\lib\site-packages\flask_security\datastore.py", line 217, in create_user
return self.put(user)
File "W:\myApp\envs\myApp_app\lib\site-packages\flask_security\datastore.py", line 34, in put
self.db.session.add(model)
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Any idea what might be going on? When I was using the SQLAlchemy with session [Link](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id2) I did have this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flask\_sqlalchemy object does not have attribute add when using flask\_security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616260/flask-sqlalchemy-object-does-not-have-attribute-add-when-using-flask-security)